# Wildcard in powershell string for call operator

Tags: powershell

In a powershell script I need to call a funcion like this

```
$SpecRunCall = "./packages/SpecRun.Runner.1.2.0/tools/SpecRun.exe"
$MSTestArguments = @('run', 'Default.srprofile', "/baseFolder:.\TestResults", '/log:specrun.log')

if($tag) {
    $MSTestArguments += '/filter:@' + $tag
}   

& $SpecRunCall $MSTestArguments
```

But I have to put there the version of the SpecRun Runner, I was thinking of putting a wildcard for that and then find whichever version I have (provided I have only one there) but I'm struggling to find a working solution for it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the only version exists, `Resolve-Path ...SpecRun.Runner.*...` should work:

```
$SpecRunCall = Resolve-Path ./packages/SpecRun.Runner.*/tools/SpecRun.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

You could the following assuming that all the `SpecRunner` version are all in different folders labeled with the version number. And that only one version folder will be on the computer at a time.

```
$version = "1.1.0","1.2.0","1.3.0"
$SpecRunCall = $null

$version | Foreach {
    # Set spec runner version folder
    $SpecFolder = "./packages/SpecRun.Runner.$_/"
    # Test folder 
    If(Test-path $SpecFolder){
        # Version folder found use it
        $SpecRunCall = $SpecFolder+"tools/SpecRun.exe"        
    }    
}

# Check if a version was found 
If($SpecRunCall -ne $null){
    # ** Your code ** 

    $MSTestArguments = @('run', 'Default.srprofile', "/baseFolder:.\TestResults", '/log:specrun.log')

    If($tag) {$MSTestArguments += '/filter:@' + $tag}   

    & $SpecRunCall $MSTestArguments
}
```

This code will take a list of version numbers and look for the corresponding `SpecRunner` folder. If found that version of `SpecRunner` is selected.